# How to refresh tab panel items in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: refresh, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I am using a tab panel (Ext.tab.Panel) that has 4 tabs and on one of the child screens when the user make a selection from a radio button group, I would like the tab panel to refresh itself (i.e. load new text, new icons). How can I force the tab Panel (which is the core navigational element of the app) to refresh?

I have tried setting the show: function() { } method on the view as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', { 
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
...
    show: function() {
        this.callParent();
        ... reload stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to modify the tabs in the tabbar, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The tabs/icons in a `Ext.tab.Panel` make up the `items` property of the component. To change these tabs/icons you must change the items.

Use [`setItems(items)`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setItems) to effectively change the tabs/icons of the `Ext.tab.Panel` inside your listener.

```
var tabpanel = Ext.getCmp('tabpanelid'); // Get appropriate panel using its id

// Removes the current tabs, and inserts the following 2 tabs
tabpanel.setItems([
    {
        title: 'Tab1',
        iconCls: 'info',
        html: 'Foo'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab2',
        iconCls: 'reply',
        html: 'Bar'
    }
);
```

[Check out a working example here.](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#FY3qi)

**UPDATE:** To modify one of the current items, use [`getItems()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-getItems), modify the appropriate items, and call `setItems(items)`.

[Updated Example](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ll8Pe)

Comment: What if I want to work at a more granular level, instead of `setItems` I just want to change the title of the items themselves like so `item.config.title = "Something New"`. How would I do this?

Comment: You can call [`getItems()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-getItems), iterate through each item in the items array, and modify the appropriate items, then call `setItems(items)` with the modified items.

Comment: Doing this causes the entire interface to go blank with the tabbar items shown but there are no tab bar items after the `setItems(items)` call - this call is made from a controller. So, I can say that this is probably not the correct method of updating the tabbar items.

Comment: More likely there is an error with the way you're handling it. Whether the call is made from a listener in the view or a method in the controller shouldn't matter as long as you're properly calling them. Make sure your `items` holds what you think it holds. If you provide more relevant code to your localized problem, then the solution can be more catered to the needs of the problem.